# Adding extra Zero's dynamically to Integer in fixed lenght format

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to display a sql column `Amount` in a format of 15 Integers and 3 decimal places (18 length).

1. Add extra zero's dynamically to complete the length 18
2. Decimal(.) will also be replaced by a Zero

For Example :

> $2,494.60 will be displayed as 000000002494060

Is it possible to achieve it using `SQL` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @amount numeric(15,3) = 2949.60
select Right('000000000000000' + replace(cast(@amount as varchar(15)),'.','0'),15)
```

Comment: Can you please recheck end of second line. I think it has some issue

Comment: the bracket was facing the other way :)

Comment: Thanks alot @Jayvee

Answer (score 1):

You can use `STR` to fix the leading and trailing decimal places, and `REPLACE` to change spaces and dots into zeroes.

Query:

```
SELECT Amount
    , PaddedAmount = REPLACE(REPLACE(STR(Amount, 15, 2), '.', '0'), ' ', '0')
FROM
    (VALUES (12345.678), (1231312), (0.12345), (0), (123456789012.45)) AS V (Amount)
```

Output:

```
Amount               PaddedAmount
-------------------  ----------------
12345.67800          000000012345068
1231312.00000        000001231312000
0.12345              000000000000012
0.00000              000000000000000
123456789012.45000   123456789012045
```